# Shortcut Target switches for Slack Desktop

Tags: windows, slack

I want to be able to do this:
`C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\slack\slack.exe -fullscreen`
or, something similar to open Slack Desktop in fullscreen mode.

The same mode that you get when you press `Ctrl+Shift+F` on Slack Desktop. I want to know the parameter so that it happens as I open the app automatically. Couldn't find the switches anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Powershell to write a script which presses Ctrl+Shift+F after starting Slack. For example:

```
& ~\desktop\Slack.lnk # launch slack
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; # initialize wscript
$wshell.AppActivate('Slack - My Workspace') # change this to the title of your slack window; activate it to receive the key combination
Sleep 10 # wait for it to open
$wshell.SendKeys('^+{F}') # press the Ctrl+Shift+F key combination
```

**References**

- [powershell - How to send CTRL or ALT + any other key? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824799/how-to-send-ctrl-or-alt-any-other-key)
- [How to perform keystroke inside powershell? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849522/how-to-perform-keystroke-inside-powershell)
- [SendKeys Method | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa202943(v=office.10))
- [Powershell comments - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-comments.html)